# Outlook rule for body text, how to specify line breaks?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible in Outlook (2007) to match things like ...

```
Hello

World
```

(i.e. I want to auto-delete when I get an email with 'Hello', then an empty line, then 'World' for example).

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just set a rule to match messages containing the words `Hello`, `World`?

Comment: because I don't want to delete messages that have something between those 2 lines (actually the lines are 'Error #:' and 'Line #:' so I want to delete messages that don't have an error # after 'Error #:'

Comment: I found [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/outlook-2003-rules-more-than-one-line-t2797120.html), looks like it is not possible in Outlook (any version of Outlook). Maybe you can filter the messages using another rule, without matching line breaks.

Comment: This approach should work: https://superuser.com/questions/987734/how-to-filter-outlook-email-using-a-rule-with-a-vba-script