# Which criteria to set when creating a rule in Outlook 365 to move all signed or encrypted emails from the Inbox folder to another folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption, office365, rules

I'm looking to create a Rule in Outlook 365 that will automatically move any signed or encrypted emails received in my primary Inbox folder to another folder (Inbox-Enc is the destination folder that I created).

I can't seem to find the proper criteria to set as part of the Rule creation process (either via the Rules Templates Microsoft offers or via building a Rule from scratch), and was wondering if anyone else had accomplished this, either through a Rule creation or via some other method that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter on
[Message Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-asemail/51d84da6-a2da-41e9-8ca7-eb6c4e72c28d).
More specifically, the ones that interest you are:

[image]

The rule should then check for a Message Class string that contains "IPM.Note.SMIME".

But there is one problem : Outlook rules do not have such a condition.

The solution is to create a rule that is based on a VBA macro.
A model macro (that I never tested) is as follows:

```
Sub filter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(1, UCase(Item.MessageClass), "IPM.NOTE.SMIME") <> 0 Then
        Set Folders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
        Set Folder = Folders.Item("folder-name")
        Item.Move Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

For more information see the post
[How to filter Outlook email using a Rule with a VBA script?](https://superuser.com/questions/987734/how-to-filter-outlook-email-using-a-rule-with-a-vba-script)

Comment: Thanks for this info @harrymc. In working through the process of implementing it, I have discovered that the security settings in my Outlook client don't allow the Action option "Run a script". I have found the registry key to modify to enable this, but I need to determine first if applying this change is even possible with the GPOs in my organization. Just wanted to acknowledge your answer and while I believe it will work, I'll get back after I get the policy question(s) answered. Thanks again!